# How to stop server ran in Daemon mode in Django?

Tags: linux, django

I ran the Django development server as:

```
nohup.out ./manage.py runserver
```

How can I stop the server?

Tried using:

`nohup.out ./manage.py stop runserver` but it's not working.

Comment: `runserver` is normally existed using CTRL+C. On what OS are you? Can you not run `top` and select and kill the process. BTW: you *want* the runserver command's errors to be visible.

Comment: No! I am running the server as daemon so Ctrl+c Ctrl+D won't work. I ran the server using nohup.out as a daemon so I want know how to stop it using the proper command. I am in Debian.

Comment: If I run `nohup python manage.py runserver` on Ubuntu I *can* exit it using CTRL+C. If that does not work on your system, use `top` to identify and kill the process.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

check the process id of python related to Django

```
ps -ef | grep python

kill -9 Process_id_no.
```

Answer (score 2):

automatically with:

```
ps -ef|awk 'BEGIN{}{if(match($8, /python/))system("kill -9 " $2)}END{}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Nohup.out is the log file from nohup.
What you want is: `nohup python manage.py runserver`
But nohup introduces it's own issues, so I'd recommend you use Screen instead.
To use Screen: `screen python manage.py runserver` once launched you can then disconnect from the session with `<Control - D>`.
Then if you need to reconnect at some point you can with `screen -x`.